# Python: how do you create an array with information about each pixel from an image?

Tags: python, arrays, python-imaging-library, pixel

For example, a 3 pixel by 3 pixel jpeg image of a checkerboard should be something like

```
[[#000000, #FFFFFF, #000000],
[#FFFFFF, #000000, #FFFFFF],
[#000000, #FFFFFF, #000000]]
```

I feel like I may need to download PIL, but I cannot tell what the module does from their website. I also need to be able to generate images from these types of arrays. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Image.getdata](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm#Image.getdata) method. The method returns a generator that you can iterate over:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("a.png")
data = img.getdata()
for (r, g, b, a) in data:
    # do something with the pixel values
```

To go the other way you use [`Image.putdata`](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm#Image.putdata). This generates a tiny checkerboard picture:

```
>>> img = Image.new("L", (3, 3))
>>> data = [0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0]
>>> img.putdata(data)
>>> img.save("checkerboard.png")
```

Here I created a grayscale image (only one "luminescence" channel) and so I just used a single integer value for each pixel.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. Only one question: how do I move to three color channels? I assume each pixel is a 3-tuple but what do put instead of "L"?

Comment: It's right there in the manual: you use [`RGB` as the mode for three channels](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/concepts.htm#mode).

Comment: @user1189737: oh, sorry! I didn't see you were so new here :-) Thanks!